# How to find the cumulative distribution function of a sum of n continuous random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider the sequence $\{t_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ of independent and identically distributed continuous random variables with distribution function $F(x)$, i.e., $P(t_n\le x)$.

Define $~~T_n=\begin{cases} 0~~ \mbox{if }~~ n=0,\\
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}t_i ~~\mbox{if}~~n\ge 1.\end{cases}$

Then how to find the distribution function of the partial sum random variable $T_n$.